# How to overcome 'Coudn't find that formation' error when adding web dynos to Heroku django app?

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to get deploy a simple django app, and have successfully pushed my git repository to Heroku. However, when I attempt to run:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

I get the following error

```
Scaling dynos... failed
 !    Couldn't find that formation.
```

Any thoughts as to what the problem might be? The contents of the Procfile  (below) are correct to the best of my knowledge.

```
web: gunicorn my_app_name.wsgi
```

Comment: What's the output of `heroku ps` after a git push?

Comment: There's no output. The terminal looks like its doing something for a few seconds, then the prompt comes back.

Comment: Very odd. Does the web UI provide any information: it should show your current configuration/dyno count (if any).

Comment: Under 'Dynos' it merely says 'No dynos'. I'm not sure if there's meant to be an option to control the number of dynos through the web interface, but none is showing up.

Comment: Just to clarify: is your `Procfile` in the root of your git repo? Can you add the output of `tree -L 2 .` to your question if not?

Comment: Yes, it is. (I get `Too many parameters - 2` when I run the `tree` command, though...)

Comment: Ah - found the problem, a bit embarrassing. I'll post an answer.

Comment: I was getting this error because I was using "Web=1" instead of "web=1" on Windows! /facepalm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ensure that your Procfile has no extension.

To create a file with no extension on Windows, you can use the command `notepad Procfile.` from the command line.

Answer (score 19):

To state the obvious: another way to encounter this issue is if you're working on a new app, and you try running `heroku ps:scale web=1` before you've actually done a `git push heroku master`. There is no `Procfile` on the Heroku server in that case, because there aren't any files at all. :D

Comment: Worked for me. :)

Answer (score 12):

To add yet another reason this can happen, my `Procfile` contained

```
web:gunicorn
```

but it should be:

```
web: gunicorn
```

As far as I can tell from all of these answers, if you run into this problem, it is very likely related to `Procfile`.

Comment: good eye. If I didn't read this It would have taken a while to discover this

Comment: This worked for me. Spent a lot of time doing many other options and it was this, the dynos scaled immediately after I changed the file.

Answer (score 7):

for those interested, I had the same problem to add a worker. to do so you need to add this line to your procfile : `worker: python worker.py`

Answer (score 2):

For others experiencing this same issue, make sure Procfile is not ignored in git.

Delete your Procfile.  Then `git status`.  If don't see anything mentioning Procfile, you need to find remove the entry from local or global .gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I missed `git add` and `git commit` the file named Procfile .

You should try to use the command `git status` and review whether the `Procfile` is included.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue while working on `windows`(haven't tested on other operating systems)and this worked fine for me.

Initially, I have created a file name `procfile` and pushed it to heroku. But, heroku expects the `Procfile` declaration. It is `case sensitive`. Hence, we should be careful while `typing the filename also`.

Even after changing the name to `Procfile` git didnt notice changes(maybe git is case-insensitive just like windows). Hence, I had to delete the file completly and had to create a new one with `Procfile` as the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

When pushing to Heroku you must come up with something like shown in the Picture. If not your procfile has an Error. 
[image]
The Procfile looks like this for my Flask app

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

Answer (score 0):

In my php project I can use

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
```

at the heroku directory "php-getting-started" (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#prepare-the-app).

So I'm try to do this in my original application, so I tried to do again in Heroku Repository and it's work.

(sorry about the english, hehe)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problme,

1) I also configured ProcFile
but the problem still available

So used this

`Remove the existing buildpacks with heroku buildpacks:clear and add them again in the right order using the heroku buildpacks:add with the --index option, making sure that the language buildpack is the last in the list`

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "Adjust buildpacks on Heroku"
git push heroku master
```

Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and tried the following:

- Made sure Procfile does not have any extension
- Procfile is spelled exactly as 'Procfile'

At the end of the day just realized that my Procfile was in my app directory.  It should be on the root/project directory.