# 'Coudn't find that formation' error when adding web dynos to Heroku flask app?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I've just installed `flask` and `heroku`, and despite not having a problem with creating a simple app, now i download .zip file with ready code i wanted add and run this app on my `heroku` profile.

I get following error:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... failed
   !    Couldn't find that formation.
```

**Procfile:**

```
web: gunicorn nameapp:app --log-file -
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've anticipated, this almost certainly relates to your `Procfile`.  Some obvious ones to check first (quoting [Heroku.com](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)):

> A Procfile is a file named `Procfile`. It should be named `Procfile` exactly, and not anything else. For example, `Procfile.txt` is not valid. The file should be a simple text file.  The file must be placed in the root directory of your application. It will not function if placed in a subdirectory.

If this doesn't help, it's possible that your `Procfile` is being ignored by `git`.  See a similar question here: [How to overcome 'Coudn't find that formation' error when adding web dynos to Heroku django app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487512/how-to-overcome-coudnt-find-that-formation-error-when-adding-web-dynos-to-her)